# How to open Laravel Backpack admin page?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-backpack

I have just installed **Laravel Backpack** admin panel using composer and artisan.

It's installed successfully but now i am trying to access it using *localhost/myprojectname/public/admin* and it's returning **404 error page**.

[image]
Can anyone help what is the reason?

Comment: What about _localhost/myprojectname/admin_?

Comment: Same problem exist

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file if u r on apache, or redirect settings. Should not be /public in path.

Comment: still same issue.